# Decay overlaid with function

Tags: python

I am trying to plot decay (1/r, 1/r^2 and 1/r^3) with my functions [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqVNQ.png)

My issue is that the decay lines are not near the function plots so it's difficult to see which decay line fits which function. I would like the decay lines to overlay the function.

I have tried subtracting a number from the 1/x function to shift it down but that did not work.

```
#load data from matlab
mat = loadmat('model01.mat')

#unpack data from matlab, one distance and velocities in 4 different directions
dist = mat['Dist_A_mm01']
distar = np.array(dist)
vpos = mat['Model_Posterior01_m']
vposar = np.array(vpos)
vant = mat['Model_Anterior01_m']
vantar = np.array(vant)
vleft = mat['Model_Left01_m']
vleftar = np.array(vleft)
vright = mat['Model_Right01_m']
vrightar = np.array(vright)

# transpose data

distar = np.transpose(distar)
vposar = np.transpose(vposar)
vantar = np.transpose(vantar)
vleftar = np.transpose(vleftar)
vrightar = np.transpose(vrightar)

#select numbers from array to plot (number in place 0 is 0 which gives an error when dividing by zero later)

dd = distar[1:50]

#plot the data from matlab in a log log graph

ax = plt.axes()
plt.loglog(distar,vposar)
plt.loglog(distar,vantar)
plt.loglog(distar,vleftar)
plt.loglog(distar,vrightar)
plt.loglog(dd,1/dd,dd,1/dd**2,dd,1/dd**3)
ax.set_title('Decay away from centroid')
ax.set_ylabel('Velocity in m/s')
ax.set_xlabel('mm')

plt.show()
```

Here is the mat file I am importing [.mat file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uH9GgDkvSw2PkFbpkp24pe-f7DO77_te/view?usp=sharing)

I want the decay lines to be overlaid with the data so it's easy to see the decay of each line on the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To shift the decay functions you need to multiply them with something smaller than one, not subtract, since log(A * 1 / x^2) = log(A) - 2 * log(x), i.e. by selecting appropriate values for A you can shift them up and down as you please. In practice this would look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(1, 10)
y = 1 / x**2
y2 = 0.1 * 1 / x**2

plt.loglog(x, y, label="1/x2")
plt.loglog(x, y2, label="A + 1/x2")
plt.legend()
```

If these lines are supposed to be just guides to the eye, that should suffice. Otherwise you should probably do a fit to your actual data.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I wanted, it worked great.